# Magnific Popup: application-3f3c3e8….js:15011Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-5, magnific-popup, turbolinks-5

I'm using this example for a gallery: https://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/zvLny

My app is Rails 5 and Turbolinks 5. **I only get this error in production, not development.**

When I click to open the gallery, I'm getting the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined`

Here's my js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // image gallery lightbox
  $('.open-gallery-link').click(function(event) {
    //  event.preventDefault();
    var items = [];
    $($(this).attr('href')).find('.slide').each(function() {
      items.push( {
        src: $(this)
      } );
    });

    $.magnificPopup.open({
      items:items,
      gallery: {
        enabled: true
      },
      closeBtnInside: false

    });
  });
```

And my html:

```
<a href="#gallery1" class="open-gallery-link">
  <div class="featured-img space-bottom-30" style="background-image: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/hdldnogif/image/upload/v1488230846/zk17kylcizbq9grz3eg8.jpg)">
 </div>
</a>
```

I tried wrapping my JS in `$( document ).on('turbolinks:load', function() { }`  but get the same error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the old syntax. Try this:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', {
  // your code here
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not valid syntax

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will help somebody!
If you do minify your JS code, then most probably that there is a short name for 'magnificPopup', it has shortened name in 'scripts.min.js', that's why in this case you can't find 'magnificPopup' - it's undefined.

Answer (score -1):

The selector of your element is wrong

```
 $.magnificPopup.open
```

. Your selector should be the anchor tag. Try with this instead:

```
$('.open-gallery-link').magnificPopup.open({});
```

Comment: I don't think that works. I'm getting this error now: ```$(...).magnificPopup.open is not a function```  I think that only works if your gallery is nested inside the $('.open-gallery-link') element. In my cause I'm trying to launch the gallery by clicking a separate link.

Comment: I think a big thing to notice here is my code works fine in development but not in production. Feels like a Rails or Turbolinks issue